# Server push framework for adobe flex 4.6

Tags: blazeds

I have a web application with adobe flex 4.6 with php as backend. The application allows collaboration of multiple users. Currently, changes made by one user are reflected to the other users only on refresh. I have taken a look at Adobe's BlazeDS requiring a java backend. This would require me to change some of the php code to java code. Is this the right way to go about it or can anyone suggest a better framework which does a server push on db update rather than having to do a refresh everytime?